# iPhone iOS get thumbnail image from Vimeo : how to turn response into an image?

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, thumbnails, vimeo

I'm trying to get video thumbnails from Vimeo, but for some reason, I cannot turn the returned NSData into a `UIImage`. Here's my code. How do I turn `NSData` of type `text/html; charset=UTF-8` into a `UIImage`?

```
-(void)getThumbnails
{
    int count = _videos.count;
    Video* v = nil;
    RKRequest* r = nil;

    for( int i = 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        v = [_videos objectAtIndex:i];


        r = [[RKClient sharedClient] get:v.thumbnail delegate:self];
        GMGridViewCell* gridViewCell = [self GMGridView:_gmGridView cellForItemAtIndex:i];
 //prints http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/257/009/257009714_200.jpg
        NSLog(@"thumbnail url: %@",v.thumbnail);

        [r setUserData:gridViewCell];

    }

}
```

Here's the response:

```
-(void)requestQueue:(RKRequestQueue *)queue didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response
{

    if([response.request.userData isKindOfClass:[GMGridViewCell class]])
    {


        //prints content type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
        NSLog(@"content type: %@",response.contentType);

        GMGridViewCell* cell = response.request.userData;

        NSData* responseBody = response.body;
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseBody];

        cell.imageView.image = image;

          }
}
```

Update:

**after checking the response as body, it appears that vimeo returns a not found page** , while typing that into an browser returns an image :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

```
r = [[RKClient sharedClient] get:v.thumbnail delegate:self];
```

was prepending the default path that is set up when the client is initialized in front of the request, creating a http:// ...http://... like path that the server did not recognize, replying with a not found message.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't help you with main question, I can clarify for you, in case you didn't know, that NSData is just a buffer of bytes essentially, so to use the [UIImage imageWithData:] message you need NSData to contain a proper image file (jpg, png etc).

If your response isn't a pure image but something else, you will need to parse your NSData to extract the image data you need.

I hope that puts you on the right track.